# DLL Crashes when built in release mode, debugger cannot catch

Tags: c++, debugging, crash

I've been attempting to debug this issue all day to no avail. Here is what I know.

My C++ DLL crashes when built in Release mode, but works perfectly fine when built in Debug mode.
Specifically it works fine when compiled with `/MDd`, but crashes when compiled with `/MD`. I'm using cmake and msbuild.

Specifically I've tracked down the issue to being the value of a string (an IP) I pass to the program. If I pass almost any IP, it works fine. If I pass a certain few IPs, this crash happens. The weird thing is that the IP is loaded into memory fine, and the code that actually uses it isn't called at all before the crash happens.

I've spent hours trying to track down the issue with x64dbg, but the crash is not caught at all, the program instantly closes after a bit of loading and then crashes and the debugger ends the session.

I unfortunately cannot provide the source code as this is a closed source (and very big) program, and tracking this down manually is proving impossible.

What would be some good steps to start debugging this? The biggest issue for me is that no debugger I use can catch the crash. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is most likely caused by undefined behaviour

Comment: Some ideas: Set all kinds of error handlers to see if anything fires (`std::set_terminate`, `std::signal`, `std::atexit`, winapi stuff). Try attaching a crashdump-generating system ([example](https://github.com/chromium/crashpad)). Try a postmortem debugger. Try an address sanitizer. Try bisecting the commits to find the culprit. Try bisecting the code to isolate the crashing part.

Comment: Can you provide the code of just the function which takes the string IP? Or find someway to reproduce the bug?

Comment: Run it through static analysis and UBsan.

Comment: Make sure that there is no mixing of Debug and Release binaries.